# How to modify the value of a key-value Pair from a map while I do not know whether the key is exist in the map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator

How to modify the vlaue of a key-value Pair from a map while I do not know whether the key is exist in the map?

for example , there is a key-value pair in a map:

```
a[5]   =    " H ";
```

//  But after  some operation,like  insert, erase etc ; I do not know whether 5  still  exist in the map,can I  modify it like this ?:

```
a[5]   =   " G ";
```

// or  I must  define a iteraotr  pos

```
pos = my_map.find(5);
if( pos !=  my_map.end())
{
 pos->second   =   " G ";
}
```

Is there any other way I can  modify a value of a  key-value Pair from a map???  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard map has the curious property that indexing into an element that is not present in the map causes an association to be created between that key and a default constructed value. So, if the element `5` is not present as a key in the map, after you do `a[5]` it will exist and be associated to an empty string.

**C++11** added a new `at` method that throws if the key does not exist in the map, which makes it possible to index into a `const map`.

Comment: 23.4.4.3/10 "Throws: An exception object of type out_of_range if no such element is present."

Comment: They didn't add a `const` overload, but they added a new `at()` method which behaves as you describe.  The only new `operator[]` overload is one for an rvalue-reference to the key.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to set the value whether it exists or not, go ahead and use the subscript operator:

```
a[5] = " G ";
```

It will create a new mapping if one didn't exist. This is guaranteed by the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

In the example with `find()` you can modify the value via the returned iterator:

```
pos->second = " G ";
```

You should use this approach if you only want to modify if it already exists as the `operator[]` will create a new entry if it does not currently exist. If you want to add it or modify it, use `operator[]`.